# The extremities of a diameter of a circle..

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

The extremities of a diameter of a circle have co ordinates $(6,-2)$ and $(6,8)$. What length does the circle intercept along $X$ axis..?

My Attempt:
Let, $(6,-2)\equiv (x_1,y_1)$ and $(6,8)\equiv (x_2,y_2)$ be the end points of diameter of circle.
Now, 
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)+(y-y_1)(y-y_2)=0$$
$$(x-6)(x-6)+(y+2)(y-8)=0$$
$$x^2-12x+36+y^2-6y-16=0$$
$$x^2+y^2-12x-6y+20=0$$

is the required equation of the circle. Now, what should I do then?

Comment: Find the intercepts on the $x$ axis by letting $y=0$, then their difference.

Comment: @dxiv, Please elaborate, a bit more. I.could not get

Comment: $y=0 \implies x^2-12x+20=0\,$, calculate the roots $x_1, x_2$, then $|x_1-x_2|\,$.

Comment: @dxiv, why is $\abs {x_1-x_2}$ need to be done?

Comment: Because "*length*" usually means a non-negative number.

Comment: @@dxiv, I mean why should the difference be taken?

Comment: `What length does the circle intercept` If the circle crosses the X axis at two points, then I guess the "*length*" in question refers to the distance between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue with your solution -

The lengths of intercepts made by the circle

$$x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$$

with X and Y axes are $2\sqrt{g^2−c}$ and $2\sqrt{f^2−c}$ respectively.

> Or -

Mid point of (6,-2) and (6,8) is (6,3).

Also radius r = $\frac 12 \sqrt{(6-6)^2 + (8+2)^2}$

= $\frac 12 \sqrt {100}$

= 5

Equation of circle is -

$(x - 6)^2 + (y - 3)^2 = (5)^2$

Put y = 0, you will get two values of x 
subtract the two intercepts to get the length of the chord.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for correcting my mistake.

Comment: @@Kanwaljit Singh, How do you get the formula i.e x intercept$=2\sqrt {g^2-c}$?

Comment: I learnt it from here. http://www.math-only-math.com/intercepts-on-the-axes-made-by-a-circle.html

Comment: Hope helps you too.

Comment: Always you write two or three times @ before name. So its not ping the user. Only write single @ before name in comment.